# AWK script automatically removing leading 0s from String

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file BLACK.FUL.eg2:

```
10>BLACK.FUL>272/GSMA/000000>151006>01
15>004401074905590>004401074905590>B>I>0011>Insert>240/PLMN/000100>>5000-K525122-15
15>004402145955010>004402145955010>B>I>0011>Insert>240/PLMN/000100>>1200-K108534-14
15>004402146016260>004402146016360>B>I>0011>Insert>240/PLMN/000100>>1200-K-94878-14
15>004402452698630>004402452698630>B>I>0011>Insert>240/PLMN/000100>>5000-K538947-14
90>BLACK.FUL>272/GSMA/000000>151006>01>4
```

I've written this AWK script:

```
awk 'NR > 2 { print p } { p = $0 }' BLACK.FUL.eg2 | awk -F">" \
'{if (length($2) == 15) print substr($2,1,length($2)-1)","substr($3,1,length($3)-1)","$6","$8; \
else print $2","$3","$6","$8;}' | awk -F"," '{if ($2 == $1) print $1","$3","$4; \
else {if (length($1) > 14) {v = substr($1,9,6); t = substr($2,9,6); \
while(v <= t) print substr($2,1,8)v++substr($2,15,2)","$3","$4;} \
else {d = $1;while(d <= $2) print d++","$3","$4;}}}'
```

which gives me an output of:

```
00440107490559,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214595501,0011,240/PLMN/000100
440214601626,0011,240/PLMN/000100
440214601627,0011,240/PLMN/000100
440214601628,0011,240/PLMN/000100
440214601629,0011,240/PLMN/000100
440214601630,0011,240/PLMN/000100
440214601631,0011,240/PLMN/000100
440214601632,0011,240/PLMN/000100
440214601633,0011,240/PLMN/000100
440214601634,0011,240/PLMN/000100
440214601635,0011,240/PLMN/000100
440214601636,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440245269863,0011,240/PLMN/000100
```

with one problem: the leading 0s of strings in field1, are automatically getting removed due to a numeric operation on them. So my actual expected output is:

```
00440107490559,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214595501,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601626,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601627,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601628,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601629,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601630,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601631,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601632,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601633,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601634,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601635,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601636,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440245269863,0011,240/PLMN/000100
```

For that I'm trying the below updated AWK script:

```
awk 'NR > 2 { print p } { p = $0 }' BLACK.FUL.eg2 | awk -F">" \
'{if (length($2) == 15) print substr($2,1,length($2)-1)","substr($3,1,length($3)-1)","$6","$8; \
else print $2","$3","$6","$8;}' | awk -F"," '{if ($2 == $1) print $1","$3","$4; \
else {if (length($1) > 14) {v = substr($1,9,6); t = substr($2,9,6); \
while(v <= t) print substr($2,1,8)v++substr($2,15,2)","$3","$4;} \
else {d = $1; for ( i=1;i<length($1);i++ ) if (substr($1,i++,1) == "0") \
{m=m"0"; else exit 1;}; while(d <= $2) print md++","$3","$4;}}}'
```

But getting an error:

```
awk: cmd. line:4: {m=m"0"; else exit 1;}; while(d <= $2) print   md++","$3","$4;}}}
awk: cmd. line:4:          ^ syntax error
```

Can you please highlight what I'm doing wrong to achieve the expected output. Modification only for my already existing AWK script will be of much help. Thanks

NOTE: The Leading 0s can be of any number of occcurence, not only 2 0s in every case as in the above example outputs.

Comment: What you have written is not an awk script, it's a shell script that calls awk multiple times to execute various awk scripts. Edit your question to add indentation and other white space to make your scripts readable and we might be able to help you.

Comment: Recommendation: if your script is no longer simple (long and/or with nested structures) it's better to create a file and run it with `awk -f scriptname`. You can format it better with a file editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since your field sizes are fixed, for the given example just change the last print statement to

```
$ awk ... printf "%014d,%s,%s\n",d++,$3,$4}}}'

00440107490559,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214595501,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601626,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601627,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601628,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601629,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601630,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601631,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601632,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601633,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601634,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601635,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440214601636,0011,240/PLMN/000100
00440245269863,0011,240/PLMN/000100
```

**UPDATE**

if your field size is not fixed, you can capture the length (or desired length) and use the same pattern.  Since your code is too complicated, I'm going to write a proof of concept which you can embed into your script.

this is essentially your problem, increment a zero padded number and the leading zeros dropped.

```
$ echo 0001 | awk '{$1++; print $1}'
2
```

this is the proposed solution with parametric length with zero padding.

```
$ echo 0001 | awk '{n=length($1); $1++; printf "%0"n"s\n", $1}'
0002
```

Comment: proposing an alternative simpler way to eliminate the code that causes the error altogether.  See the quote "...Modification only for my already existing AWK script will be of much help."

Comment: @karafka my field size is not fixed to 14, it can be anything between 1 to 16

Comment: @dig_123: What defines the field size then? Width of input?

Comment: @dawg entirely depends on input

Comment: @dig_123: That is circular. You say that karakfa's solution is not right, but you are not defining what 'right' is. If you don't know, how is anyone else going to know?

Comment: @karafka embedded in my script, works fine for me now. Thanks much